# LS vs MLE for Gaussian Conditional Random Field estimation

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix, generalized-least-squares

Is there such a thing as Least Squares estimation for the conditional mean and covariance of a conditional gaussian random field?

I'm looking at this paper by [Wytock and Kolter 2013](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/wytock13.pdf), in which they set up a tractable convex optimization for the $l_1$ penalized MLE estimates of $\Theta$ and $\Lambda$ for the conditional model $y|x \sim N(-\Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top x, \Lambda^{-1})$. 
(This is just the conditional distribution derived from a centered Gaussian joint, parameterized in terms of blocks in the inverse joint covariance matrix, which are better suited to regularization [Sohn and Kim 2012](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sssykim/papers/377_paper.pdf).) 
Wytock and Kolter mention in passing (bottom of p. 2) that this (unregularized) optimization is "simply a reparameterization of the least squares problem." This is what I'd like to understand: what is Least Squares in the context of covariance (or precision, $\Lambda$) estimation?

The MLE objective of this problem is
$$f(\Lambda,\Theta) = -\log|\Lambda| + \text{tr}\bigl( S_{yy}\Lambda + 2 S_{yx}\Theta+ \Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top S_{xx} \Theta\bigr) \, ,$$ where $S_{yy}$ is the sample covariance of $y$, $\frac{1}{m}Y^\top Y$, and similarly $S_{yx} = \frac{1}{m}Y^\top X$.

If asked set up least squares estimation of these parameters (I only really understand the conditional mean estimation part), I would think to write down
$$\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i + \Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top x_i)^\top (y_i + \Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top x_i) \, ,$$
or maybe $$\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i + \Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top x_i)^\top\Lambda (y_i + \Lambda^{-1}\Theta^\top  x_i) \, .$$

The latter one (weighted least squares?) works out to the the same as the MLE objective, except there's no $\log |\Lambda|$ term. Can anybody enlighten me what the least squares problem that includes conditional covariance estimation really is, and whence it picks up the log det term? I can see that it acts as a barrier to keep $\Lambda$ PD, and to prevent you from "cheating" by sending $\|\Lambda\| , \|\Theta^\top \| \to 0$, but that's not a real explanation.

The background is that my professor philosophically abhors MLE, but I want to use the results from this literature.

Comment: There is not much you can do about the last point!